# MySQL syntax error when trying to delete a row in a database table using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to delete a row in my database but I am getting a syntax error.
May I know how can I solve this error?

first_lesson.books database

[image]

```
import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetFactory;
import javax.sql.rowset.RowSetProvider;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class RowSetLesson {
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
    static String userName = "root";
    static String password = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ResultSet resultSet = getResSet();
//        while (resultSet.next())
//            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("name"));

        CachedRowSet rowSet = (CachedRowSet) resultSet;
        rowSet.setCommand("SELECT * FROM first_lesson.books WHERE price > ?");
        rowSet.setDouble(1, 30);

        rowSet.setUrl(url);
        rowSet.setUsername(userName);
        rowSet.setPassword(password);
        rowSet.execute();

        rowSet.absolute(2);
        rowSet.deleteRow(); // The error occurs when you try to delete a row. 
                            // If you remove this line of code, the project will compile
        rowSet.beforeFirst();
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        rowSet.acceptChanges(connection);

        while (rowSet.next()) {
            String name = rowSet.getString("name");
            double price = rowSet.getDouble(3);
            System.out.println(name + " " + price);
        }
    }

    static ResultSet getResSet() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
             Statement stat = conn.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from first_lesson.books");
            RowSetFactory factory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
            CachedRowSet crs = factory.createCachedRowSet();
            crs.populate(rs);
            return crs;
        }
    }
}
```

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.books WHERE bookId = 2 AND name = 'Harry Potter' AND price = 45.5' at line 1
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)

```
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)

at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972)

at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.deleteOriginalRow(CachedRowSetWriter.java:974)

at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.writeData(CachedRowSetWriter.java:341)

at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:894)

at java.sql.rowset/com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.acceptChanges(CachedRowSetImpl.java:956)
at lesson4.RowSetLesson.main(RowSetLesson.java:37)
```

> Exception in thread "main" javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncProviderException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.books WHERE bookId = 2 AND name = 'Harry Potter' AND price = 45.5' at line 1

I want to understand why an error occurs, because when watching a training video from the author, the code compiles without errors. The code is the same, checked many times

Comment: The queries showing the error are not the ones you posted

Comment: I can show a screenshot of the output message to the console. This is exactly what the console shows me for my executed code, I don’t understand why

Comment: Need to show the code for function `deleteRow`, since that is where your comment claims the error happens.